# ng-repeat doesn't work properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use `ng-repeat` but it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-init="jj=[1,2,2,3]">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in jj">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output screen is blank. The output source (taken from browser's inspect element):

```
<html class="ng-scope" lang="en" ng-app=""><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-init="jj=[1,2,2,3]">
    <ul>
      <!-- ngRepeat: x in jj -->
    </ul>
  <!-- Code injected by live-server -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
    if ('WebSocket' in window) {
        (function() {
            function refreshCSS() {
                var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
                    var elem = sheets[i];
                    head.removeChild(elem);
                    var rel = elem.rel;
                    if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") {
                        var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, '');
                        elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf());
                    }
                    head.appendChild(elem);
                }
            }
            var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://';
            var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws';
            var socket = new WebSocket(address);
            socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
                if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload();
                else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS();
            };
            console.log('Live reload enabled.');
        })();
    }
    // ]]>
</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console.

Comment: @webpersistence were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [duplicates in your array](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes), try [using `track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) like:

`ng-repeat="x in jj track by $index"`

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-init="jj=[1,2,2,3]">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in jj track by $index">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have duplicate element in the array

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in jj track by $index">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/cudukaqejo/edit?html,output)**

You can read more about track by at following url

[track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)